# Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11 not support iPhone 4 (iOS 7)?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, iphone

I am trying to connect my iPhone 4 (iOS 7) to Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11, the iTunes does not show the device. At first I thought it may be cable or anything causing it. But when I try to plug the iPhone 4 to Mac OS X Lion 10.7, it works. The device does show up in the iTunes.

Why is that the phone does not show up in iTunes on Mac OS X 10.11? Is it because it is not supported?

Comment: I just managed to connect an old 3G, so it's not the OS or iTunes. OS X 10.11.2 iTunes 12.3.1 iOS I'm guessing at 6.1.2, but didn't check